# Removing all empty columns and rows in data.frame when rows don't go away

Tags: r, function, loops, dataframe, na

I have two data.frames, `dA` ([HERE](https://github.com/izeh/m/blob/master/irr3.csv)) and `dB` ([HERE](https://github.com/izeh/m/blob/master/irr4.csv)). They are exactly the same EXCEPT that `dB` has one completely empty column and multiple empty rows.

```
dA <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/izeh/m/master/irr3.csv", h = T)
dB <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/izeh/m/master/irr4.csv", h = T)
```

I want remove all empty columns and all empty rows in `dB` so that `dB` becomes exactly like `dA`.

Currently, I try the following to achieve my goal ***but it looks like empty rows don't get removed***:

```
# remove columns with all NA
B1 <- dB[, colSums(is.na(dB)) != nrow(dB)]

# remove rows with all NA
B2 <- B1[rowSums(is.na(B1)) != ncol(B1), ]   # NOW, check by:  `nrow(B2)` the `NA` haven't 
                                             # been removed !!
```

Comment: @NelsonGon, this question is different!

Comment: It's generally better to include sample data with your question that does not link to an external site. The repo may be archived/deleted in the future. `dput` is one of several better options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `NA` and also empty rows. You can do

```
B1[rowSums(is.na(B1) | B1 == "") != ncol(B1), ]

#   study.name  group.name outcome ESL prof scope type
#1  Shin.Ellis    ME.short       1   1    2     1    1
#2  Shin.Ellis     ME.long       1   1    2     1    1
#3  Shin.Ellis   DCF.short       1   1    2     1    2
#4  Shin.Ellis    DCF.long       1   1    2     1    2
#5  Shin.Ellis  Cont.short       1   1    2    NA   NA
#6  Shin.Ellis   Cont.long       1   1    2    NA   NA
#8    Trus.Hsu       Exper       1   2    2     2    1
#.....
```

We can also use `filter_all` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
B1 %>% filter_all(any_vars(!is.na(.) & . != ""))
```

Comment: you can specify `na.strings` in `read.csv` and include everything that you want to convert to `NA`. For example, this would have worked for you `dB <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/izeh/m/master/irr4.csv", h = T, na.strings = c("NA", ""))`

Comment: Ronak, what is the difference between `setNames(x, sub("\\.\\d+$", "", names(x)))`  and `setNames(x, sub("\\.\\d+", "", names(x)))`? One has an extra `$` sign?

Comment: @Reza `$` represents end of the string. So in first case `.number` would be removed if present at the end of string and in second it would be removed from anywhere in the string.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option with `Filter` from `base R`

```
Filter(function(x) !all(is.na(x)), dB)
#  study.name  group.name outcome ESL prof scope type
#1  Shin.Ellis    ME.short       1   1    2     1    1
#2  Shin.Ellis     ME.long       1   1    2     1    1
#3  Shin.Ellis   DCF.short       1   1    2     1    2
#4  Shin.Ellis    DCF.long       1   1    2     1    2
#5  Shin.Ellis  Cont.short       1   1    2    NA   NA
#6  Shin.Ellis   Cont.long       1   1    2    NA   NA
#7                              NA  NA   NA    NA   NA
#8    Trus.Hsu       Exper       1   2    2     2    1
#...
```

Or with `any`

```
Filter(function(x) any(!is.na(x)), dB)
```

---

To remove the rows

```
B1[!!rowSums(!is.na(B1) & B1 != ""),]
```

Or using `Reduce`

```
B1[Reduce(`|`, lapply(B1, function(x) !is.na(x) & x != "" )),]
```

Comment: Arun, what is the difference between `setNames(x, sub("\\.\\d+$", "", names(x)))`  and `setNames(x, sub("\\.\\d+", "", names(x)))`? One has an extra `$` sign?

Comment: @Reza  Is this based on the same post.  The difference is based on a typo.  It should have been `$` in both.  If there is only a single instance of `.\\d+`, then both would work.  but otherwise, can give different result.  Here, the `$` is to make sure that it is the end of the string

Comment: @Reza  I updated my comment.  It is basically a typo, but should work in cases where there is only a single instances of `.` followed by one or more digits

Comment: One other thing regarding that post, what is the difference between `x[setdiff(names(x), ar)]` and `x[ , !names(x) %in% ar]` where `x` is a data.frame and `ar` is a vector of name characters?

Comment: @Reza The former returns only the `unique` names.  If you have duplicates, it will be dropped, while the latter gives a logical output (`TRUE/FALSE`) for the full length and using that your duplicates names won't get dropped

Answer (score 1):

You can use `replace` to convert `""` to `NA` and use then `is.na`. To remove complete rows and colls you can use `apply` with the function `all`.

```
x  <- is.na(replace(dB, dB=="", NA))
dB[!apply(x, 1, all), !apply(x, 2, all)]
```

or using `rowSums` and `colSums`, like in the question:

```
x <- is.na(dB) | dB == ""
dB[rowSums(x) != ncol(x), colSums(x) != nrow(x)]
```